# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

LINE Botをつくりたく、下記RubyプログラムをHerokuのURLにアクセスするという形で実行したところ、

```
callback.rb:19:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

とのエラーが発生しました。
どのメソッドが未定義？Nil?なのでしょうか。そして、どうすれば解決するのでしょうか。

いっぽうLINE側のWebhook URLにherokuのurlを登録してVERIFYすると、

```
A http status of the response was '503 Service Unavailable'.
```

というエラーが返ってきます。
これは上のundefined methodエラーが原因なのでしょうか？

ソースコードはこのサイトを参考にしました。
http://qiita.com/mix_dvd/items/b0065d9adb8f486838c4

```
#!/usr/local/bin/ruby
# encoding: utf-8

# ライブラリの読込
require 'cgi'
require 'json'
require 'line/bot'

# CGIの生成
$cgi = CGI.new()

# 送信されたデータの整形
params = {}
$cgi.params.each {|key, val|
  params = JSON.parse(key)
}

# 返信に必要な情報の取得
replyToken = params["events"][0]["replyToken"]
msgType = params["events"][0]["message"]["type"]

if msgType == "sticker" then
  msgText = "イイね！"
else
  msgText = params["events"][0]["message"]["text"]
end

# 返信データの作成
message = {
  type: 'text',
  text: msgText
}

# データ送信
client = Line::Bot::Client.new { |config|
    config.channel_secret = "[自分のチャンネルシークレットを入力]"
    config.channel_token = "[自分のチャンネルトークンを入力]"
}
response = client.reply_message(replyToken, message)
#p response

# 初期認証用コード
puts <<EOF
Content-type: text/html

linebot
EOF
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINE Botの仕様は存じませんが、

> ```
> callback.rb:19:in `<main>'
> ```

ということですので19行目を見ると、

> ```
> replyToken = params["events"][0]["replyToken"]
> ```

エラーメッセージを見ると、

> ```
> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
> ```

ということなので、  `nil` に対して、定義されていないメソッド `[]` を使用してしまったということです。`[]` がいくつも登場していますので、ここでは、

`params` が `nil` か( ここに対して `["events"]` で `[]` メソッドを使用している)
`params["events"]` が `nil` か( ここに対して `[0]` で `[]` メソッドを使用している)
`params["events"][0]` が `nil`( ここに対して `["replyToken"]` で `[]` メソッドを使用している)

の可能性がありますね。

ここで気になりましたが、

> ```
> params = {}
> $cgi.params.each {|key, val|
>   params = JSON.parse(key)
> }
> ```

`each` のなかでせっかく初期化した `params` そのものに毎回代入しています。このため、意図した形の `params` が出来ていないのではないでしょうか。

もしかしたら、正しい代入は `params[key] = JSON.parse(key)` なのでは?

Comment: params[key] = JSON.parse(key)に書き換えて再度実行しましたが、やはり同じエラーとなりました。

Comment: `params` の内容は確認しましたか?

Comment: 内容の確認とは、nilチェックですか？以下のコードでnilかどうかを確かめてみましたが、回避できませんでした。  if params[key].nil? == true then
    p "nil"
  else
    params[key] = JSON.parse(key)
  end

Comment: @sashihara とりあえず、例外の発生している行のすぐ上で `p params` してみると良いのではないでしょうか?

Comment: p paramsしたところ、 {} が出力されました。

Comment: @sashihara JSON.parse(key) のすぐ上で、params, key, value を表示してみるとか? (この場に記載しない方が良さそうなデータがあったら伏せてくださいね)

Comment: params,key.valueを表示させようとしたところ、そもそも$cgi.params.eachのループに入りませんでした。ところで、このプログラムはLINEからPOSTされたデータを処理するものなので、いまのところはparamがnilでも問題がないのでしょうか？

Comment: @sashihara  私も sakuro さん同様、LINE Bot については知りませんので、それは判断できません。が、使わないのなら空でも問題ないと思いますよ。